# py.test on Ubuntu

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I try to run a series of test cases on Ubuntu with py.test and is not collecting my test cases from a folder. I use unittest to write test cases.

On Windows i use this command:

```
py.test –v "folder with test cases" > log_file.txt
```

The output from Windows:

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 2.6.3 -- py-1.4.20 -- pytest-2.5.2 -- C:\Python26\python.exe
plugins: capturelog
collecting ... collected 27 items
```

Same command on Ubuntu, the output is:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.3 -- pytest-1.3.4
test path 1: TestScenario01/

===============================  in 0.01 seconds ===============================
```

I use different Python versions, because on Windows Scapy works only with Python 2.6. Another difference is that on Windows appears py-1.4.20 and pytest-2.5.2. I have them installed on Ubuntu too.

Comment: Are your test cases prefixed with `test_`?

Comment: They are `testTS0x`. And i have setup.cfg:            `python_files=*.py
python_classes=TS*
python_functions=test*`

Comment: Right well check http://pytest.org/latest/goodpractises.html#test-discovery just to be sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to start tests. I had to remove the old py-1.3.4 module and install py-1.4.2 and also had to upgrade pytest to version 2.5.2. Now it works.